# Custom ListView items shifting the listview to left?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview, imageview

My custom list-view has some sort of a unique problem and I am unable to track where the problem lies.
     The custom list-view is for a chat application that I am creating, in which I am dynamically adding text-views with the user entered messages. With each text-views added the list-view is getting shifted to the left-side of the screen and the text view[image] is getting cut on left side, I searched a lot what could be the reason but couldn't find any, can someone help me with this issue??
     The image shows the gap that increases on the right-side with every entry.
and here is the xml code`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatheader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/headershowfriends" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/namechatfriend"
        style="@style/Text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="demo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frdstatus"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/online" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/msgboxll"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chatheader"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/msgboxll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearchat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/headershowfriends"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/smiles"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_smile" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageBx"
            style="@drawable/edittext"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.80" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
            style="@style/button_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text="@string/send" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.pack.coderzheaven.SlidingPanel
        android:id="@+id/popup_smilywindow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbckgnd"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridViewsmily"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
        </GridView>
    </com.pack.coderzheaven.SlidingPanel>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

and this is the my adapter 
`

```
public class ChatMessageAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<Chat>
{
        List<Chat>listmsg=new ArrayList<Chat>(); 
        Activity context;
        Bitmap bitmapfriend,bitmapuser;
        public ChatMessageAdapter(Activity context,List<Chat> listmsg, Bitmap friendimage, Bitmap userimage) 
        {
            super(context, R.layout.list_row_layout_even, listmsg);
            this.listmsg=listmsg;
            this.context=context;
            this.bitmapfriend=friendimage;
            this.bitmapuser=userimage;
        }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        try 
        {
            try 
            {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        String type=listmsg.get(position).getType();

        if(type.contentEquals("even"))
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_even, parent, false);
            TextView textLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textLabel.setText(listmsg.get(position).getMessageSpannable());
            ImageView image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rightProfilePic);
            if (bitmapuser==null) 
            {

            }
            else
            {
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmapuser);
            }   
        }
        else if(type.contentEquals("odd"))
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout_odd, parent, false);
            TextView textLabel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            textLabel.setText(listmsg.get(position).getMessageSpannable());
            ImageView image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.leftProfilePic);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmapfriend);
        }           
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }       
        return (convertView);
    }
```

}
`

Comment: Not related to your question but check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType(int) instead of using the odd/even index to determine the type of view to use.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for the helping me, my issue got solved automatically after I created a new xml. Sounds weird but it happened .